# How the program running on a server can listen user input

Tags: perl, server, client, cgi

I have a natural language parser binary, e.g.`parser`, that requires much time for starting (from the terminal) but after it is running, the parsing takes input from a terminal and processes it in less than a second.

I have a perl cgi script that takes the input from a client and runs the parser (with `qx/parser/`) on the server with that input. 
Unfortunately, in this way the parser is loaded for each input.

Is there a way that the parser will be running and listening the input from clients? That every input won't require loading the parser.

Comment: Can you tell us more about that parser? Is it an open source project that has public documentation? You will need to run it as a daemon and make your CGI program talk to it somehow. Look at its documentation to see if it offers more than just STDIN/STDOUT, and look at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html for interprocess-communication.

Comment: It is written by me and has only STDIN/STDOUT option. Thanks I will have a look at IPC.

Comment: If you have control over it, add some other mode of communication. :)

Comment: You could make a persistent process that loads the parser, listens on a socket for requests, passes the requests on to the parser , and returns the parser's response back over the socket. But I wouldn't do that. I would simply the CGI script itself persistent by switching to FastCGI.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old problem (already seen with inetd) with various solutions.

A simple solution would be to add RPC::Lite to the process that runs permanently (as a daemon) and write a minimal client that contacts the daemon process, sends the request and receives the answer.

The example at https://metacpan.org/pod/RPC::Lite has pretty much everything you need. You can use a unix socket as transport if both tasks run on the same machine.